# Holders.config is null during grails run-war

Tags: java, logging, grails, log4j, log4j2

Recently did a log4j upgrade on grails 2.5.4 application. Following dependencies pertaining to v2.17.1 have been added:

- log4j-api
- log4j-core
- log4j-1.2-api
- log4j-slf4j-impl

I've excluded the following dependencies from the global level:

- log4j
- grails-plugin-log4j
- jcl-over-slf4j

The application boots up without any issues on doing `grails run-app`. But when I try to run the war by `grails run-war` or deploy the war using tomcat, I keep getting:

```
Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'xyz' on null object
```

This null object is `Holders.config`

This issue occurs during static property initialization. The class looks like:

```
class Test {
    public static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this)
    private static final String SOURCE_URL = Holders.config.xyz.abc
    ...
}
```

Another class had the same issue during the initialization of variable using `Holders.config` in static block.

Strangely, this issue is only for classes under *grails-app/utils* folder because I've another class under *src/groovy* where its variables are defined in a similar way but there's no issue with it during the war file execution.

There's no change in code except for the dependencies added/removed as mentioned above.
I also tried using `applicationContext.getBean('grailsApplication).config.xyz.abc` but it said `Could not find ApplicationContext, configure Grails correctly first`.

Can someone please suggest what could be the root cause or guide how I can fix or maybe initialize these static values.

Comment: There isn't any good reason to do `private static final String SOURCE_URL = Holders.config.xyz.abc`.  What the right thing to do depends on the context in which this is happening.  If the value is needed in a Spring managed bean you have several options.  See https://grails.org/blog/2016-08-31.html and https://grails.org/blog/2017-01-20-3.html.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown These are utility classes defined under grails-app/util folder. We are not considering them as beans. The only reason to do it was to set the values during class initialization itself. Although, this used to work before I upgraded log4j2 dependencies, and am not sure how that could impact Holders.config.

Comment: If you can share a simple example project which demonstrates some use case that you think may be best served by that static constant, I would be happy to send a PR showing an efficient approach.